Characterization of normal coordinate chart
Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $(U, \varphi = (x^1,...,x^n))$ is a smooth chart at $p \in M$ satisfying the following

$\varphi(p) = 0$ and $\varphi(U)$ is star shaped with respect to the orgin
$g_{ij}(p) = \delta_{ij}$
$x^i(q)x^j(q)\Gamma_{ij}^k(q) = 0$ for all $q \in U$

With these assumptions, I am trying to prove that $(U, \varphi)$ is a normal chart. In particular, I would like to show that $U$ is a normal neighborhood and $\varphi \circ \mathrm{exp}_p$ is a linear map.
For each $q \in U$, let $(v^i) := \varphi(q)$ and $\gamma(t) := \varphi^{-1}(v^1t, ..., v^nt)$. By assumption 1, $\gamma$ is well-defined on $[0,1]$. Assumption 2 implies that $\gamma$ is a geodesic such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma(1) = q$. Let $\Lambda(q) := \gamma'(0)$. Then $\Lambda : U \rightarrow \mathcal{E}_p$ is a right inverse of $\mathrm{exp}_p$.
Now, I am not sure how to show that $\Lambda$ is a left inverse of $\mathrm{exp}_p$. For $v \in \mathrm{exp}_p^{-1}(U)$, construct $\gamma$ as above with $q = \mathrm{exp}_p(v)$. Then $\gamma'(0) = \Lambda(q) = \Lambda(\mathrm{exp}_p(v))$. But, I am not sure how to prove that $\gamma'(0) = v$. A priori, it seems to be possible that $\gamma'(0) \ne v$ and still $\gamma(1) = q$, for example, geodesics in a 2-sphere from the north to the south pole.
I would appreciate any hint or insight.
